# Is this property true essentially by definition? If not, how do I derive it?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

The property is:

$\frac{dF(\vec r(t))}{dt} = \vec \nabla F(\vec r(t)) \cdot \vec r'(t)$

I can understand that this is essentially an equivalent of the chain rule, where the gradient of $F(\vec r(t))$ is the equivalent of "the derivative of F with respect to $\vec r(t)$". Intuitively, that makes sense. But, is that because of the definition of the gradient, or is there a way to show it?

Comment: It is literally the chain rule. The way to prove it is expanding the left hand side.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz Oh, I checked the definition for the multivariable case along a line and it is indeed the definition. Well, guess that solves that, lol.